# On the numerical computation of polynomial roots

Tags: equation-solving, algorithm

In the guide on the `NRoots[]` function I read:

```
Possible settings for the Method option include: 
"Aberth", 
"CompanionMatrix",
"JenkinsTraub".
```

Now, as the third method is definitely out of my league, I focused on the other two:

**1]** example of implementation of the *Aberth-Ehrlich method*:

```
p[x_] := (x - 1) (x - 2) (x - 3)

n = Length[CoefficientList[p[x], x]] - 1;
z = Table[Exp[2 π I (k + 0.01) / n], {k, 1, n}];
For[i = 1, i <= 100, i++,
    For[j = 1, j <= n, j++,
        sum = Sum[If[k != j, 1/(z[[j]] - z[[k]]), 0], {k, 1, n}];
        z[[j]] = z[[j]] - p[z[[j]]] / (p'[z[[j]]] - p[z[[j]]] sum)
       ]
   ];

Print[z]
```

> {3. +0. I, 2. +0. I, 1. +0. I}

**2]** example of implementation of the *CompanionMatrix method*:

```
FullQRDecomposition[mat_] := Module[{q, r, n, m},
  {q, r} = QRDecomposition[mat];
  {n, m} = Dimensions[mat];
  {Join[q, NullSpace[q]], Join[r, Table[0, {n - Length[r]}, {m}]]}]

A = N[NRoots`CompanionMatrix[CoefficientList[(x - 1) (x - 2) (x - 3), x]]];

n = Length[A];
For[i = 1, i <= 100, i++,
    If[i == 1, k = Exp[I], k = A[[n, n]]];
    {Q, R} = FullQRDecomposition[A - k IdentityMatrix[n]];
     A = R.ConjugateTranspose[Q] + k IdentityMatrix[n]
   ];

Print[Diagonal[A]]
```

> {3. -7.02847 10^-16 I, 2. -8.46969 10^-16 I, 1. +5.60242 10^-16 I}

Now, I'm aware that these are two toy codes, but at least they can be considered acceptable in the context of the most frequent and not too extreme applications? Otherwise, would you have any counterexample where they fail? Furthermore, are the two algorithms always interchangeable or are there cases in which it is better to prefer one over the other?

Thank you!

Comment: As far as acceptable goes I’d prefer someone providing me code to use the built in functions unless they can give a convincing argument why that’s not good enough

Comment: @MichaelE2: I'm sorry that the message has passed that I'm not satisfied with the integrated functions, only my curiosity to deepen the thing a little by putting into practice theoretical concepts studied in books (even if they're far from a complete satisfactory understanding).

Comment: I suspect either method will have trouble with multiplicity. Also high degree can be problematic for implementations of various root-finders. That might give an idea of where to look for problematic examples.